# what is process avpppnvxrk? its using high cpu

Tags: server, process

I ran a server running on an older ubuntu os and was sitting for a year or two and just started using it again.. I installed ettercap and this process avpppnvxrk is maxing out the cpu.

I ran `dpkg -S avppnvxrk` and it's unknown. I uninstalled ettercap but it's still running.

I've googled, bing'd and yahoo'd  and each search was unable to find this at all anywhere. It has files in /etc/rc1.d, rc2.d, up to rc5 and in init.d and then /usr/lib/update-rc as well as the exec in /usr/bin.

I would like to find what it belongs to before I just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your server was compromised. Malware often uses random process names to escape detection, which would explain why none of your searches turned anything up and why `dkpg` didn't know about it.

You need to wipe the server clean and reinstall a fresh copy. You mentioned you were using an older version of Ubuntu. Make sure you keep the new install up to date!  Tons of security fixes come through the pipes every week. If you don't get those updates something like this will eventually happen. Hopefully you've been keeping good backups of any important data, because you can't trust any of it now.